# introducing graphical books

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am teaching mathematics to high school students. I am searching for any graphical books which helps student to learn better, I am looking for a graphical book for precalculus and combinatorics. Any help wold be great thanks

Comment: What do you mean, graphical book?

Comment: Do you mean curve sketching? If so, see my list under *Classical Surveys of Curve Sketching* [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13530/which-book-has-functions-and-their-respective-graphs/13535#13535). Do you mean [geometrical drawing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22geometrical+drawing%22)? Do you mean [mechanical drawing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mechanical+drawing%22)? Do you mean [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) in the combinatorics sense?